# Practicing big O and finding recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I'm preparing for a Data Structures/Algorithms exam and I wanted to do some practice problems dealing with finding recurrence relations for recursive functions and big O run times for snippets of code...can anyone point me in the right direction(online resources preferred)?

Comment: Did you try starting with some book exercises? There is http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html by Dasgupta,.. You could refer Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen ( that I think would keep you engaged for hours together I suppose..)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? [The archive of interesting code](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/) It includes implementation o f all kinds of data structures and algorithms.